# Object detection within image using cv2 and Python

Tags: python, computer-vision, object-detection, opencv

I have this image [image]

and I am interested to find the object (i.e., points) within this image and draw a rectangle around each object. I came to know that with `cv2` and found out this can be done easily. So I have written so far following codes by some quick google search:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2 

print( cv2.__version__ )

# source data
img_file= "data1.png"

# create an OpenCV image
img= cv2.imread(img_file)

plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')

# Define the classifiers

# pre-trained classifiers 
Point_classifier="haarcascade_eye.xml"   

# convert color image to grey image

gray_img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# CREATE TRACKER

point_tracker=cv2.CascadeClassifier(Point_classifier)

# detect points
points= point_tracker.detectMultiScale(gray_img)
print(points)

Here I used `haarcascade_eye.xml` it looks similar to the point feature of the image, Is this correct? or do I need to use another classifier for this object?
```

But the result is not as expected. I am expecting figure something like this where each point should be marked with a rectangular shape individually.

Any help on this or where I am making mistake in my codes. Thanks in advance.

[image: this]

Answer (score 3):

`haarcascade_eye.xml` is used to detect human eye. There are even separate ones for left and right eye. Do not use that.

Your code-line `points= point_tracker.detectMultiScale(gray_img)` is failing because no eye is detected in your image. You should use `SimpleBlobDetector` in this case. Within `SimpleBlobDetector`, you may filter for threshold, area, circularity, convexity, inertia etc according to your requirements. I tried that but my kernel keeps dying perhaps because it is a large image. Try a smaller one.

But we can try other methods - I found contours and then filtered them based on area to avoid small points.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2 

# source data
img_file= "data1.jpg"

# create an OpenCV image
img= cv2.imread(img_file)

# convert color image to grey image
gray_img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

im_gauss = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_img, (5, 5), 0)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(im_gauss, 127, 255, 0)
# get contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

margin = 40
# calculate area and filter 
for con in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(con)
    if 100 < area < 500:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(con)
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x-margin, y-margin), (x + w+margin, y + h+margin), (0,255,0), 2)
        
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
```

[image]

If you would like to group 3-4 points into one - you may try :

1- create a big bounding box when you have overlapping bounding boxes.

2- Closing operation - (Dilation followed by erosion) before finding contours.

Comment: Thanks that worked for me. But it is very difficult to see the rectangle area when data points are close together. Is there is any way by which we can easily identify those data points?. Plus when I zoom the image resolution became poor, is there is any way to get of this. I mean get the final image with high quality.

Comment: Glad to help. Yeah nearby data points are a pain. There is no ready-made solution. Try the two options I listed at the end of my answer. Please accept the answer if it worked for you. Rather than zooming, display the image in bigger resolution (use plt's figsize). We are not touching the original image anywhere in processing, so it has nothing to do with resolution deterioration

Comment: Sry to disturb you again. How can I calculate the coordinates (top, bottom, width, length) of each rectangle of each point?